# Query a percentage of users based on multiple select statements

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to select all who have answered 'Crunchy' and also answered 'Straight' and return that as a percentage of all users who have answered 'Crunchy'.

The end game is to be able to produce a fact such as '70% of users who answered Crunchy also answered Straight'.

```
|id |question_id | user_id | answer   |
|-------------------------------------|
|1  |   1        |  81     | Crunchy  |
|2  |   1        |  82     | Crunchy  |
|3  |   1        |  83     | Smooth   |
|4  |   2        |  81     | Straight |
|5  |   2        |  82     | Diagonal |
|6  |   2        |  83     | Diagonal |
```

Pseudo code would be something like the following:

```
((Select all unique users where answer === Crunchy && where answer === Straight)

/

(Select all unique users where answer === Crunchy)) 

* 100 = %
```

So far I have a query to select all users who answered Crunchy and also answered Straight:

```
SELECT *
    FROM
    ((SELECT *      
        FROM answers
        WHERE (question_id = 1 AND answer = 'Crunchy')) A

    JOIN

    (SELECT *       
        FROM answers
        WHERE (question_id = 3 AND answer = 'Straight')) B

    ON A.user_id = B.user_id ) 
    GROUP BY A.user_id
```

This will select all users who have selected both answers but I need to have it as a sum so I can divide it by a second query which will be the same as the first but without the join, so essentially this;

```
SELECT *      
        FROM answers
        WHERE (question_id = 1 AND answer = 'Crunchy'
```

And then multiply the answer of that by 100.

How do I complete the rest of this SQL query or is there a more simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to correlate them.

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 0, 0, COUNT(a2.user_id)/COUNT(*)*100) AS percentage
FROM answers AS a1
LEFT JOIN answers AS a2 ON a1.user_id = a2.user_id 
    AND a2.question_id = 2 AND a2.answer = 'Straight'
WHERE a1.question_id = 1 AND a1.answer = 'Crunchy'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` for the `a2` columns when there's no matching row with `answer = 'Straight'`. And `COUNT(a2.user_id)` only counts the non-null values, so this counts all the users who answered `Straight`. Meanwhile, `COUNT(*)` counts all the rows, which is all the `Crunchy` answers.

The `IF()` protects against division by 0 if there are no Crunchy answers.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks Barmar. A lot more succinct that what I had originally as well.